# Why hash code is same for String s1= "cat" and String s2= new String("cat")?

Tags: java, hashcode

**Program :**

```
 class JavaCode
     {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
      {
        String s1 ="cat";
        String s2 = new String("cat");
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
     }
  }
```

**Output :**

```
false
98262
98262
```

If S1 and S2 are pointing to different memory address, then Hash code should be different for them? Please Explain how they are same?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: That is not how hash codes work.

Comment: You're mixing pointers wtih hashcodes

Comment: Hash code is a number using a hashing strategy. It has nothing to do with memory location which would be a very bad choice for a hash code for too many reasons to mention in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`If S1 and S2 are pointing to different memory address, then Hash code should be different for them?`

No, this is not how hash codes work. If two objects are `equal`, their hash code MUST be equal too. It doesn't matter "where in memory" they sit.

I recommend reading through the following article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html

Answer (score 3):

A hashcode is based on the **content** of some object.

Whereas == compares references, or in other words: "positions" in memory.

Thus two objects can very well have the same [`hashcode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) (because, well: same content); but belong to two different references.

And that by the way why you always always always compare Strings using the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method; and not ==.

Comment: One could argue that == is for string references, and equals for strings themselves. But good point.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()):

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object
>   is computed as  `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]` using
>   int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is
>   the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation.

Since both string has same values in it, hashcode are same.

c has ASCII value 99, a has 97 and t has 116. So,

```
hashcode of s1 = 99 * 31^2 + 97 * 31^1 + 116 = 95139 + 3007 + 116 = 98262.
```

Also hashcode for s2 will be 98262. That's how equal values makes hashcode same.

Answer (score 0):

`hashCode()` is the public instance method of `String` class, which return the integer value based on the content.

```
    class JavaCode
     {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
      {
        String s1 ="cat";
        String s2 = new String("cat");
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
      }
     }
```

In the above code, the content of `s1` and `s2` is same ("cat"), so the integer which is being returned is same.